# custom tag containing data in option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am having a list of stuff that the user can select. The way it's currently made, we have an integer as name, a price as value but i need to add a color. It's not unique so i cannot use ID.

example :

```
<option name='6' value="30.95">6 Orange(30.95$/month)</option>
<option name='6' value="33.95">6 Green(33.95$/month)</option>
<option name='10' value="32.95">10 Orange(32.95$/month)</option>
<option name='10' value="35.95">10 Green(35.95$/month)</option>
```

I need to combine two non-unique values and them to be accessible by jQuery / Javascript

I would like not to make two selects. I know it's straightforward the easiest solution but if i could stick to a single one that would give better results.

Is it safe to create a custom tag like "prodcolor" with any non-reserved nametag or is there a smarter way to achieve this?

Many thanks once again.

Comment: You could use a css class for this, no? ps JScript != JavaScript don't know if this was a typo :-)

Comment: I didn't know. Updated the question. Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use HTML5 `data-` attributes, which is invented for this very purpose. More importantly, the values of the `data-` attributes can be accessed using JS.

Since you want to include colour, you can use the `data-colour` attribute, for example:

```
<option name='6' value="30.95" data-colour="orange">6 Orange(30.95$/month)</option>
<option name='6' value="33.95" data-colour="green">6 Green(33.95$/month)</option>
<option name='10' value="32.95" data-colour="orange">10 Orange(32.95$/month)</option>
<option name='10' value="35.95" data-colour="green">10 Green(35.95$/month)</option>
```

*Even better:* Actually, you shouldn't even use the `name` attribute to store your quantity. Why not use `data-quantity` instead? :)

```
<option data-quantity="6" value="30.95" data-colour="orange">6 Orange(30.95$/month)</option>
<option data-quantity="6" value="33.95" data-colour="green">6 Green(33.95$/month)</option>
<option data-quantity="10" value="32.95" data-colour="orange">10 Orange(32.95$/month)</option>
<option data-quantity="10" value="35.95" data-colour="green">10 Green(35.95$/month)</option>
```

---

**Some background:**

There's a [nice guide published by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) on how to use JS to access such attributes. Note that it is recommended to use dash (`-`) separated attributes, instead of any other naming convention, e.g. `data-product-name` instead of `data-productName`. This is because the `.dataset` method in JS converts dash-separated data attributes into camelCase. So `data-product-name` will be accessible via `.dataset.productName`, for example.

jQuery also allows you to access the values of `data-` attributes via the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) methods. The only difference is that:

- `.attr()` is not cached, so you can use it to access dynamically-modified `data-` attributes, while `.data` only reads data attributes at runtime.
- `.attr()` can be used to read *and* write data attributes, but `.data()` can only be used to read data attributes from the DOM. `.data()` is also used to access the jQuery data object that is not written to the DOM.

---

**Usage example:**

Using your code above, we can create a simple example of alerting the colour of the product upon the firing of the `change` event:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    var $choice = $(this).find('option:selected')
    alert('Colour: ' + $choice.attr('data-colour') + '\n' + 'Price: $' + $choice.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option name='6' value="30.95" data-colour="orange">6 Orange(30.95$/month)</option>
  <option name='6' value="33.95" data-colour="green">6 Green(33.95$/month)</option>
  <option name='10' value="32.95" data-colour="orange">10 Orange(32.95$/month)</option>
  <option name='10' value="35.95" data-colour="green">10 Green(35.95$/month)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome! I'm still a little new to web stuff and i'm glad veteran users here take the time to write up good stuff. Thanks a lot buddy and have a nice day!

Comment: @Quardah You only have yourself to thank — you have a well-formulated question with a specific problem statement and provided code samples that other people can work with. Only if other questions are of such quality as yours :)